# Excel - Transposing Data into Rows when Condition Met

Tags: excel, rows, transpose

I am really hoping there is a neat way of doing this, as I am tearing my hair out at the moment.

My excel table looks like this :

```
Company | Department   | Area   | Project1_B | Project1_A | Project2_B | Project2_A | Project3_B | Project3_A

Company1  Department1    Area1    High         Medium                                 High         Low
Company1  Department1    Area2                               Low          Medium
Company2  Department1    Area1    Medium       Medium        High         Low
Company2  Department2    Area1                                                        Low          High
```

Essentially, for every row (representing an area in the organisation), there are before (b) and after (a) statuses for a number of projects (projects1-100)

Not all rows will have values for every project, as seen above, but each project will always have a 'pair' (i.e a before and after status).

The output I am trying to achieve looks like this :

```
Company   |  Department  |  Area   |  Project_Name   |  Before   |  After
Company1     Department1    Area1     Project1          High        Medium
Company1     Department1    Area1     Project3          High        Low
Company1     Department1    Area2     Project2          Low         Medium
Company2     Department1    Area1     Project1          Medium      Medium
Company2     Department1    Area1     Project2          High        Low
Company2     Department1    Area1     Project2          High        Low
Company2     Department2    Area1     Project3          Low         High
```

Where only 'non blank' records are transposed. There should be a row for each project that an area has worked on.

I have tried various transpose methods and VLOOKUPS, to no avail. Its frustrating because I suspect its a pretty simple solution but any searches I've made arent quite what I am looking for!

Is what I am looking to do possible, either with formula or VB, or am I better dumping the data into a database and trying that?

Thanks for any help,

Comment: Is this duplicate a typo? `Company2     Department1    Area1     Project2          High        Low`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to to this is using VBA.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TransposeData()
Dim FromSheet As Worksheet
Dim ToSheet As Worksheet
Dim FromColumn As Integer
Dim FromRow As Integer
Dim ToRow As Integer

Set FromSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ToSheet = Sheets("Sheet2")

ToRow = 2
For FromRow = 2 To FromSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  For FromColumn = 4 To FromSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count Step 2
    If FromSheet.Cells(FromRow, FromColumn) <> "" Then
       ToSheet.Cells(ToRow, 1) = FromSheet.Cells(FromRow, 1)              ' Column A: Company
       ToSheet.Cells(ToRow, 2) = FromSheet.Cells(FromRow, 2)              ' Column B: Dept
       ToSheet.Cells(ToRow, 3) = FromSheet.Cells(FromRow, 3)              ' Column C: Area
       ToSheet.Cells(ToRow, 4) = FromSheet.Cells(1, FromColumn)           ' Column D: Project before (from heading)
       ToSheet.Cells(ToRow, 5) = FromSheet.Cells(1, FromColumn + 1)       ' Column E: Project after (from heading)
       ToSheet.Cells(ToRow, 6) = FromSheet.Cells(FromRow, FromColumn)     ' Column F: Data - Before
       ToSheet.Cells(ToRow, 7) = FromSheet.Cells(FromRow, FromColumn + 1) ' Column G: Data - After
       ToRow = ToRow + 1
     End If
   Next FromColumn
 Next FromRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the duplicate lines in your results (5 & 6) is an error, this is a relatively simple Pivot operation (with no aggregation, and following an Unpivot) using Power Query.

If you change your original table, a `Refresh` will update the results table.

- With a cell in the table selected: `Data => Get & Transform => From Table/Range`
- In the PQ UI, select tdhe first three columns: `"Company", "Department", "Area"`, then `Unpivot other columns`
- The resultant attribute column will then have the `Project1_B, etc`.

  - Split that column on the Underscore
  - Replace the `B` with `Before` and the `A` with `After`
- Select the `Attribute.2` column and Pivot

  - Values column = Value
  - Advanced options "Don't Aggregate"

**MCode**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Company", type text}, {"Department", type text}, {"Area", type text}, {"Project1_B", type text}, {"Project1_A", type text}, {"Project2_B", type text}, {"Project2_A", type text}, {"Project3_B", type text}, {"Project3_A", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Company", "Department", "Area"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("_", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Attribute.1", "Attribute.2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Attribute.1", type text}, {"Attribute.2", type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Attribute.1", "Project_Name"}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Renamed Columns","B","Before",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Attribute.2"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","A","After",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Attribute.2"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Replaced Value1", List.Distinct(#"Replaced Value1"[Attribute.2]), "Attribute.2", "Value")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

**Source Data**

[image]

**Results**

[image]